# Does an achievement system exist on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: achievements, nintendo-switch

Does the Nintendo Switch have an achievement system like trophies on PlayStation or achievements on Xbox?
Has Nintendo Switch any board with progress in games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Switch doesn't have an achievements/trophies system like other consoles. Sadly.
You can only rely on in-game achievements.

The closest thing you can get is that some Switch porting versions from Xbox (that require a Microsoft account) can let you unlock achievements on your Xbox profile, like Minecraft and Ori and the Blind Forest.